# zombie : ajax call don't work

Tags: ajax, zombie.js

I'm using behat/mink with zombie.js for testing.
Everything workedwell so far, until I wanted to test an ajax call.
I'm using an API (fixer.io) to convert money. This part works well : the user choose the original currency, number of items, set the price and the amount is automatically converted into euro.

In my **js test** with zombie, I fill every fields and the user should see the amount in original currency + converted in euro. But the converted amount doesn't show on the page : the ajax call always return error.
then I saw this issue https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/417 .

There is absolutely no way to test xhr sync with zombie ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with the **Use Promises** part of this answer [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323)
And the by telling to behat to wait for my ajax callback.

```
/**
* @Given I wait
*/
public function iWait()
{
    $this->getSession()->wait(5000);
}
```